# I am trying to install pillow module on my python django web.. but is not installing in cpnael linux server

Tags: python, django, linux, server, python-imaging-library

Collecting Pillow==2
Downloading Pillow-2.0.0.zip (1.4 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.4/1.4 MB 8.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved when pillow version 8.0.0 was installed ( "A version difference between the Python version on my hosting server raised this issue" )

[image]

Comment: pip install Pillow==8.0.0